# what is purpose of 'named' in Lagom

Tags: lagom

In the following code, I think that the services are given a name hello. Who uses this information? ServiceLocator?

```
named("hello")
      .withCalls(
        pathCall("/api/hello/:id", hello _),
        pathCall("/api/hello/:id", useGreeting _),
      )
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This name `hello` is name of the service used by service locator.

Note, to register with the service locator, you would need to set `withAutoAcl`:

```
named("hello")
      .withCalls(
        pathCall("/api/hello/:id", hello _),
        pathCall("/api/hello/:id", useGreeting _),
      ).withAutoAcl(true)
```

Without providing `withAutoAcl(true)`, the service would start but will not be registered with the service locator. And hence you would need to make a call directly to it (on its port), rather than via the service gateway (which by default is 9000).

By marking it true, service gateway gets configured automatically, to forward the `hello` related service calls to your implementaion.